# how to make a stretchable blog header

Tags: css

while editing the template of my blog i saw that header size is set to 660px by the css property

```
width:660px
```

.Now i want to make my header spread across the whole lenth of the browser and also i don't want to specify some specific length in pixels ,so that the blog don't look odd in widescreen vs normal monitors .how do i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
width: 100%
```

should do the job. (Incidentally, if your header is a `div` or other block element, you can leave the width value away altogether or set it to `auto`. It will then assume the full width of the surrounding container (in this case, probably the browser window) no matter whether you've specified borders or paddings.